# angular js auto refresh with asp.net core mvc

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to display a list of orders in an asp.net mvc core 2 application.

I am working with angular js 4.

What i want to do is to refresh the list in the webpage when another user creates a new order.

I do not know where to start. I have looked at signalr but it is very heavy (websockets). Is there a way to do this directly with angular and asp.net core mvc ?

Thanks

Comment: web sockets ? signalr (still work in progress for asp.net core)

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to do this without signalr ? (i mean only with angular)